# How is the Agiel made?

Tags: the-sword-of-truth

Is there an explanation in Sword of Truth of how Mord-Sith's [Agiel](http://sot.wikia.com/wiki/Agiel) is made?

Comment: I don't seem to remember one. But it'd be interesting to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A wizard did it.

As far as I can recall the only mention of how Agiels are made is an offhand comment made by one of the Mord-Sith something along the lines of Lord Rahl crafts each Agiel himself and imbues them with their magical effect.